# Adding method to the class from outside of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I want to add **method1** to my class from outside of my class. Also I want to call method1 from inside of my class in order to  changing the 'homework' to 0

```
def method1(self):
    print("Processing.....")
    print("Done :D")
    self.homework = 0

class S:
    homework = 10
    def homeworkremover(self):
        S.method1 = method1
        S.method1()

a = S()
print(a.homeworkremover())
```

But I've received an error code:

```
TypeError: method1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Can you help me out pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example seems quite contrived, I can't quite see the use of it in its current form (adding a new method on a class from within a method that is being executed on an instance of the class).

But to make it work nevertheless, simply replace:

```
Sss.method1()
```

with

```
self.method1()
```

since the added method is intended as an instance method and not a class method.

On a side note, instead of

```
Sss.method1 = method1
```

it might be better to use:

```
self.__class__.method1 = method1
```

(less dependent on the class name, and works better as well in class inheritance scenarios)

Comment: Well, no those are two different things semantically. Whether it works "better in inheritance situations" depends on what you *intend*

Comment: If I use Sss.method1(self) instead of Sss.method1(),what would happen?Would method1 belong to Sss class?

Comment: Ok guys I've solved my problem thanks for your answers